# Multiple activities with same urlScheme opens package manager

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-deep-link

I'm trying to create an Android app where multiple activities need to be opened via deeplink, and I want to use the same urlScheme but different host for them.

So my android manifest looks like this:

```
<activity
        android:name=".Activity1"
        android:exported="true"
        >
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="my-app" host="screen1"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
<activity
        android:name=".Activity2"
        android:exported="true"
        >
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="my-app" host="screen2"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

However, when I try to open the activities using the urls:
my-app://screen1
my-app://screen2

Android opens the package manager and asks me to choose between 2 versions of my app (which I'm assuming are the 2 screens), and depending on the app I choose from the package manager, it opens that respective screen.

How can I keep the same scheme for both the activities, and be able to deeplink correctly to both of them?

Comment: Shouldn't this be an ideal behaviour? You are using same urlScheme for 2 different deep link intents, Android OS would be confused for where the intent needs to be routed to ... I would have used different schemes to avoid this. I am not sure why you are using same schemes.